# TypeError - Profile is not a class in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, ruby-on-rails-5, typeerror

All of a sudden, this model is start to giving me this error: 
[image]

Error message:

```
TypeError at /sv/dashboard
Profile is not a class
```

I have no idea how to debug this since the server log only shows the same error with no stack trace.

[image]

I'm running `rails 5.0.6`.

Any ideas how I should solve or debug this?

Comment: what do you mean by *All of a sudden* ? Did you change anything ? How do you call your instance(s) of Profile inside your dasboard ?

Comment: does it work if you name it differently? Like Profile2

Comment: @sovalina I haven't changed anything.

Comment: @coorasse I tried to rename the class to UserProfile and I still got the same error but with the changed class name.

Comment: Do you have an ApplicationRecord model, yes?

Comment: @coorasse I do, and it is the default one for rails. 
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base;  self.abstract_class = true; end

Comment: You probably defined Profile as `module` somewhere.

Comment: @khiavreoy I have not. I renamed the class but got the same error.

Comment: Try `spring stop` and restart the rails server.

Comment: I don't see the `end` keyword at the end of your class in the above image to signal Rails that it is indeed a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be that I had defined a controller called `ProfilesController` inside the project but within an `Api` scope and it was clashing with `::ProfilesController`:

```
class Api::ProfilesController
end
```

Removing/renaming this class along with its routes fixed the problem.